# Can I delete a checkbox option through script without deleting the entire item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to be able to delete a single choice from a question on my form through gscript without deleting the entire question and I'm not sure if this is even possible to do

Comment: google apps script, which was also written in the tags

Answer (score 3):

#### Flow:

- Get the checkbox item
- Get all choices of that item as a array
- Filter that array to remove the choice you don't want
- Set the filtered array back as choices to that item

#### Snippet:

```
function removeOption1() {
  var cbItem = FormApp.getActiveForm()
    .getItems(FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX)[0]
    .asCheckboxItem();
  cbItem.setChoices(
    cbItem.getChoices().filter(function(choice) {
      return choice.getValue() !== 'Option 1';
    })
  );
}
```

#### To read and practice:

- [Checkbox Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#getChoices())
- [Array#Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Is there a way to filter the array without using a string value,  like if I had a variable equal to an array of strings and wanted to delete all of those choices in the array without making a separate function for each one

Comment: @mias Yes. You'd use array.indexOf() to return Boolean to the filter function.